# CHEVALLEY-EILENBERG cohomology of polynomial vector fields

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

Let be $A$ the Lie algebra of polynomial vector fields. A p-cochain $C$ of $A$ is a p-linear  alternate map from $A^p$ to $A$. For $p=0$, $C$ is an element of $A$. The coboundary operator $\eth$ is defined as follow:
\begin{multline}
\eth C (X_0,...,X_p) =  \sum _{0\leq i \leq p }   (-1)^i [X_i,C(X_0,...,\hat{X_i},...,X_p)] +\\ \sum _{0 \leq i < j \leq p} (-1)^{i+j} C ([X_i,X_j],...,\hat{X_i},...,\hat{X_j},...,X_p),
 \end{multline}
$C$ a p-cochain and $X_0,...,X_n \in A$. As we can see $\eth C$ is a p+1-cochain if $C$ is a p-cochain.

Let be $Z^p (A)$ the space of all p-cocyle $C$ ($\eth C=0$) and $B^p(A)$ the set of all p-coboundaries $C$ ($C=\eth C'$). Since $\eth ^2 =0$, $B^p (A)$ is a subspace of $Z^p(A)$ and  $H^p(A)=Z^p(A)/B^p(A)$ is called $p^{th}$ cohomology space of $A$.

My goal is to compute $H^2(A)$, the 2-cocycles are:
\begin{align*}
Z^2(A)=\{ C:A\times A \rightarrow A : [X_0,C(X_1,X_2)] -[X_1,C(X_0,X_2)] + [X_2,C(X_0,X_1)] \\ -C([X_0,X_1],X_2 ) + C([X_0,X_2],X_1 ) - C([X_1,X_2],X_0 ) =0\},
\end{align*}
and the 2-coboundary are:
 $$B^2(A)= \{ B : A\times A \rightarrow A : B (X,Y)= [X,CY] + [CX,Y]-C[X,Y] \} $$
In wich condition two 2-cocycle $C_1$ and $C_2$ have the same class in $H^2(A)$?  On other hand $C_1-C_2 \in B^2(A)$.

Comment: This is a rather non trivial computation. Have you looked in the book by Fuchs on cohomology of infinite dimensional lie algebras? He discusses the cohomology of algebras of vector fields closely related to the ones you want.

Comment: Could you give me the exact title and author of this book?

Comment: If you Google for "Fuchs cohomology infinite dimensional lie algebras" you will immediately find all that.

Comment: BTW, I have no idea what the result is but since what you want is the second cohomology with values is in the adjoint representation, and my guess is that this lie algebra is rigid (is, it does not deform) the answer should be zero.